# I have a strange align on my table

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a table. And the last column of every row has a strange align-left without using any class of bootstrap which use that align.

```php
<table class ="table table-bordered">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="col-md-4">Nom du client : <?php echo"$row->nom_ent";?></td>
      <td class="col-md-4">Type d'intervention :
        <select name="intervention" id="intervention" class="form-control">
          <option value="1"<?php if($row->id_type == 1){echo "selected";} ?> >D&eacute;pannage</option>
          <option value="2"<?php if($row->id_type == 2){echo "selected";} ?> >Garantie</option>
          <option value="3"<?php if($row->id_type == 3){echo "selected";} ?> >Maintenance</option>
          <option value="4"<?php if($row->id_type == 4){echo "selected";} ?> >Installation</option>
          <option value="5"<?php if($row->id_type == 5){echo "selected";} ?> >Formation</option>
          <option value="6"<?php if($row->id_type == 6){echo "selected";} ?> >Mise en service</option>
        </select></td>
      <td class="col-md-4 text-left" colspan="2">N&deg; de projet : <?php echo"<input class=\"form-control\" type=\"text\" name=\"Num_chantier\" value=\"$row->num_chantier\" /> "; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="col-md-4">Techniciens :<br>
        <?php echo"$row->tech"."faire un split un mec par ligne"." <br>CA :"; ?>
      <td class="col-md-4">D&eacute;placement : <?php echo"$row->temps_deplacement"." <br>Temps de travail :  "."$row->nb_heure"."<br>";if($row->fini == 1){echo"<b>Travail <font color ='red'>Fini</font></b>";}else{echo"<b>Travail <font color ='red'>Non Fini</font></b>";} ; ?></td>
      <?php
                        $rMat=$pdo->prepare("SELECT id_bon, mat.nom_materiel, mat.quantite_materiel FROM materiel_bi mat WHERE id_bon = :id_bon");
                        $rMat->bindParam(':id_bon', $row->num_bon, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                        $rMat->execute();
                        $rsMat=$rMat->fetchAll();
                        ?>
      <td class="col-md-2">Type matériel :<br>
        <?php foreach($rsMat as $rowm){echo $rowm->nom_materiel."<br>";}?></td>
      <td class="col-md-2" >Quantité :<br>
        <?php foreach($rsMat as $rowm){echo $rowm->quantite_materiel."<br>";}?></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I see class `text-left` try to no delete it

Comment: i tried it because i wanted to see if it would stop it. But nothing changed

Comment: kindly add a jsfiddle link for better understanding.

Comment: To get answers good and fast, please strip your example to the necessary parts. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: The problem is on the column : Quantité & N&deg; de projet :

Comment: @Sanjeev K Don't make snippets out of everything. Snippets are for HTML, not for PHP.

Comment: @MrLister Alright, got it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please check this line?

```
<td class="col-md-4 text-left" colspan="2">N&deg; de projet : <?php echo"<input class=\"form-control\" type=\"text\" name=\"Num_chantier\" value=\"$row->num_chantier\" /> "; ?></td>
```

If not solved then add one class and do force align using !important. Not good practice but if code is too messy it saves time.

Comment: I tried the !important and nothing worked i can send you a screenshot of my problem if you want [Screenshot](http://hpics.li/9f41019) @Saugat Bhattarai

Comment: Look at the last comment i send it

Comment: how to see that pic ... and the site in different language

Comment: Just click on the link. It will shows you the picture. It's in french on the screenshot you can see the align on the last column of every row

Comment: got it let me see it

Comment: I tried to modify the class .text-left. But nothing worked. I did text-align: left !important;

Comment: can you inspect using dev tool? Its a bit time consuming for me. I am sure there is padding or margin-left behind. Then try to add class in last <td class="col-md-2 clearleft" > and fix this using css with !important if its difficult to find the actual origin.

Comment: I found the problem with the dev tool. Thanks mate. The problem is from the first child. Thanks to bootstrap 
table tr td:last-child {
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 1px;
    text-align: right;
}

Comment: Always remember, if you are doing client side scripting dev-tool is your best friend for debugging.

Comment: But to avoid the problem i have to overload the css class of bootstrap. I don't really know how to do

Comment: Try to inspect there should be some padding or margin. overloading the css class of bootstrap might solve problem today but in production if you upgrade your bootstrap to newest version all your changes will be washed out. Try finding some good youtube tutorial to inspect properly, so that its easy to find bug.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. The problem was from bootstrap. I create a style on my page. To overwrite the class of bootstrap to be able to use the text-align:left;
I used an id on :

```
<td class="col-md-4" id="n_projet" colspan="2">N&deg; de projet : <?php echo"<input class=\"form-control\" type=\"text\" name=\"Num_chantier\" value=\"$row->num_chantier\" /> "; ?></td>


<style>
   .table-bordered > tbody > tr:last-child > td.col-md-2
    {
     white-space: nowrap;
     width: 1px;
     text-align: left;
    }
   #n_projet
    {
     white-space: nowrap;
     width: 1px;
     text-align: left;
    }

</style>
```